# Good authorize.net PHP libraries

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm working on a PHP project and am looking for a good authorize.net gateway. I want something with mature code that's tested. The goal is to avoid writing and testing the entire thing myself based on the authorize.net api docs.

Does anyone know of any good PHP libraries for this? I've search Google to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Authorize.net provides its own [SDK for PHP and other languages](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/). There is probably no need to look elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure they provided these when I asked the question originally... There was only a spec. :)

Comment: @markwatson I'm sure it wasn't cause I implemented one around the same time and if they'd had an SDK I'd have used it :)

Comment: I looked at their SDK....and decided to implement my own. Their SDK is more confusing than plain REST API integration.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck. This is what I use (for the SIM gateway):

```
include("../../simdata.php");
...
<!--form action="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="POST"-->
<FORM action="https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="POST">
<?
$x_description = "website.com";
$currency = "";
$tstamp = time();
// Seed random number for security and better randomness.
srand(time());
$sequence = rand(1, 1000);
$data = "$x_loginid^$sequence^$tstamp^$total^$currency";
#echo "data = $data\n";
#echo $x_tran_key;
$fingerprint = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $data, $x_tran_key));
# php 5 only $fingerprint = hash_hmac("md5", $data, $x_tran_key);
echo ("<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='" . $sequence . "'>\n" );
echo ("<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='" . $tstamp . "'>\n" );
echo ("<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='" . $fingerprint . "'>\n" );
echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x_description\" value=\"" . $x_description . "\">\n" );
echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x_login\" value=\"$x_loginid\">\n");
echo ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x_amount\" value=\"$total\">\n");

?>
<input type="hidden" name="x_first_name" value="<?=firstName($_SESSION['user']['name'])?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_last_name" value="<?=lastName($_SESSION['user']['name'])?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_company" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['company']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_address" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['address']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_city" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['city']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_state" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['state']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_zip" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['zip']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_phone" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['phone']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_email" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['email']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="x_cust_id" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['username']?>">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="x_logo_url" VALUE= "https://secure.authorize.net/mgraphics/logo_99999.gif">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM">
<!--INPUT type="hidden" name="x_test_request" value="TRUE"-->

<!--input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_method" value="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_text" value="Click for listings">
<input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_url" value="http://website.com/confirmation.php"-->

<input type="hidden" name="x_relay_response" value="TRUE">
<input type="hidden" name="x_relay_url" value="http://website.com/confirmation.php">
<input type="hidden" name="<?=session_name()?>" value="<?=session_id()?>">

<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
<? if ($total==0) { ?>
    <a href="account.php">Your Account</a>
<? } else { ?>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Accept Order">
<? } ?>
</form>
```

And this is what I use for the confirmation.php

```
include("../../simdata.php");
#print_r($_POST);

// verify transaction comes from authorize.net and save user details
$responseCode = $_POST['x_response_code'];
if ( $responseCode == 1) { // approved
    $md5 = $_POST['x_MD5_Hash'];
    $transId = $_POST['x_trans_id'];
    $amount = $_POST['x_amount'];
    $myMD5 = strtoupper(md5("$x_tran_key$x_loginid$transId$amount"));
    #echo $myMD5;
    #print_r ($_POST);
    #print_r ($_SESSION['user']);

    if ($myMD5 == $md5) { // authenticated response from authorize.net
       ...
    } else {
        $error = "Unauthenticated response.";
    }
} else if (isset($_POST['x_response_code'])) { // error
    $error = $_POST['x_response_reason_text'].", #".$_POST['x_response_code'].'.'.$_POST['x_response_subcode'].
        '.'.$_POST['x_response_reason_code'];
}
```

Comment: Just a note that $x_tran_key isn't the Authorize.Net Transaction Key. It is the MD5 Hash that one generates on their account under Settings. I was running your code over and over and couldn't get it working until I figured this fact out.

Comment: Is there any actual security penalty for using this method? What attacks is this still open to?

Comment: Knowing more than I did then, I would not use `rand`, but instead use `mcrypt_create_iv`. If I did this today, I would use their API.

Answer (score 5):

The form method is an insecure way of transmitting this information. A better bet is using their API AIM method.

A great tutorial can be found here:
http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrating-the-authorizenet-aim-api-with-php

Answer (score 2):

Magento supports Authorize.Net. Extract out the code you need as Magento is well tested and good quality code.

Comment: I think he was looking more for a ready-to-go solution. Digging through magento's code might be more work than he is looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think simdata.php just contains the transaction data... like the amount, the person's firstname, etc.

Answer (score 2):

James Gifford created some Authorize.net code for codeigniter.  Download here...

http://jamesgifford.com/programming/codeigniter-authorize-net-library/

I'm using the php sdk I got straight from Authorize.nets dev site...

http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

this is a decent library to use in CodeIgniter, but it can be used stand-alone:

http://code.google.com/p/authorizenetlib/downloads/detail?name=Authorize_net-1.0.php

credit: james gifford for the code.

Comment: The link no longer appears to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Payment module included in Kohana 2.3.x with the built-in Authorize.Net driver.  http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/payment

Answer (score 0):

http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-authorizenet-aim-interfacing-class.html

That is the class I use. Fairly simple to use. You're still going to need to dig into the API though, to figure out what variables you want to send and which ones you don't.